# wxThread documentation example usefull or bad coding practice?

Tags: c++, multithreading, wxwidgets, friend

I have a C++ wxWidgets program, that uses threads. Therefore I needed to make sure the threads are safely accessed. In the [wxThread documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_thread.html) it is explained how to do so. They use `friend`classes and `wxCriticalSection` to secure their threads. I did it like in the example and it works fine, though when I talked to a collegue about it, he told me friend classes are evil and should be avoided alltogether to avoid unexpected behaviour. I should use [`wxMutex`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1/classwx_mutex.html) instead.

Now I understand his point, because having my `main` as a friend class gives the thread class complete access to it. I understand, that this can cause problems, for example if I have similarly named variables or uninentionally access something else that I should not use outside of main. But I wonder if there are any advantages of this method. I mean, there has to be something, otherwise I can't understand why this way should be (as the only way) described in the wxWidgets documentation?

Could someone please enlighten me about the advantages and disadvantages of both methods? Or is there maybe a third way how I can access only the `wxCriticalSection` from the main without using `friend` or making it public? Thank you for your help.

---

*Edit*: As I realized that the critical part in my code is an artifact from long time ago, that is not neccessary anymore, the question is not vital for my programming. Nevertheless I think this is an interesting topic and would be usefull for future situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 completely orthogonal things in this question:

1. Using `friend` is indeed a bad idea and the example in `wxThread` documentation could (and should) be rewritten to avoid it. The simplest way to do it would be to reset the thread pointer in `wxEVT_COMMAND_MYTHREAD_COMPLETED` event handler.
2. `wxCriticalSection` is semantically exactly the same as `wxMutex` and, in fact, under non-Windows platforms they are just exactly the same. Under Windows, `wxCriticalSection` is just a more efficient kind of mutex (both classes directly correspond to their counterparts in Win32 API). It's perfectly fine and, in fact, preferred, to use `wxCS` instead of `wxMutex` if all you use it for is protecting some shared data. You need to use `wxMutex` with a `wxCondition` however.

Comment: So if I got it right, they could have used wxMutex instead of wxCriticalSection in the example, nevertheless it is bad practice to solve the problem like this with the `friend`class?

Comment: `friend` is bad practice, yes. But there is no need to use `wxMutex` here, `wxCS` is perfectly fine. And, again, these 2 points have nothing to do with each other.